# Issues while running JUnit on maven project using Spring JTA

Tags: spring, maven, junit, jta

I have a Spring + Hibernate project deployed on JBoss 5. It was using Ant earlier and recently I have modified the project structure to use Maven 2. But all the code and config files are the same.

I am using Spring JTA for transaction management in my project. I am able to perfecly buid the project and deploy it on JBoss. But when I try to execute the JUnit tests it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.checkUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:473)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:413)
```

The wierd thing is that this was working perfeclty fine when I was using Ant. It started coming after the migration to maven.

This is the entry in spring-jpa-conf.xml file:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
</bean>
```

And this is the Junit code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-conf.xml" })
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
public abstract class LocalUsersTestBase {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="books-lemf")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    protected void getUsersDetails(List<Users> out) {
            ..........
}
```

I also tried to add a property in the config file entry as shown here:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:/TransactionManager"></property>  
    </bean>
```

But it gives the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: JTA UserTransaction is not available at JNDI location [java:/TransactionManager]; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.lookupUserTransaction(JtaTransactionManager.java:548)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.initUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:425)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
```

Please help.

Thanks!!

This is my complete spring config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
        </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="books-pu" 
        jndi-name="java:/books-emf" 
        cache="true"
        lookup-on-startup="false"
        proxy-interface="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"
    />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="booksDataSource" jndi-name="java:/books-ds"/>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firsty, from spring reference documentation

> If you use JTA in a Java EE container then you use a container
>   DataSource
>   , obtained through JNDI,
>   in conjunction with Spring’s
>   JtaTransactionManager
>   . This is what the JTA and JNDI lookup version
>   would look like:

[image]

> The
>   JtaTransactionManager
>   does not need to know about the
>   DataSource
>   , or any other specific
>   resources, because it uses the container’s global transaction management infrastructure

then when you run the tests you need to a environment container managed to get a JTA User Transaction. In addition can you share with us the complete spring configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using a Datasource in my config file.

Comment: I have pasted the complete contents of my config file.

Comment: I think that the property jndi-name is bind to your application server. During the test phase you don't have an environme container managed and the you got the above exception. Try to use arquillan for this kind of test